# how resolve hibernate Envers Configuration Error?

Tags: hibernate, spring, hibernate-envers

Hi here i am using hibernate hbm file to all model class. Now I need to audit the details of that class. I tried to use hibernate envers. I had created a new class with `@Audited` annotation . Then i cofigured my `hibernate.cfg.xml` with my new class and Envers Configuration like `<listener class="org.hibernate.envers.event.AuditEventListener" type="post-insert"/`>,etc.

While I start apache I got the

> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in file

I am very new to hibernate envers... I googled it... but I could not understand...
can anyone help me how reslove it...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full error message. The half you have doesn't contain any useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Setup logging for the [`org.hibernate`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging) category, there is something preventing the `SessionFactory` from being created and the cause is probably in the logs.